# Systematized way to analyze "nested" data

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, categorical-data, inference

I would like to analyze a dataset that looks like the following:

```
library(data.table)

dataset <- fread("
x1  x2  y
A   A1  0
A   A2  1
A   A3  1
B   B1  0
B   B2  1
B   B3  0
")
```

and the properties A1, A2, A3 are only relative to A, as well B1, B2, B3 to B and not have any column x1=A and x2=B1 for example. And I would like if there is a method to deal with this dependency between columns. I think I can't just fit a linear model with those, and I don't know any tests that work in this situation. One path I think that could be possible is create a third column "x1*x2" with x1 and x2 concatenated and the proceed to fit a linear model, or make some common tests.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can't fit a linear model, then what kind of model do you have in mind?  You do seem to be describing the linear model `y ~ x2`.  How does your conception differ from that?

Comment: I can fit a linear model, but a would like to see the impact of x1

Comment: It would help, then, to state that in your question, rather than suggest you are looking for a nonlinear model.  By properly coding your variables you can get your regression software to test $x_1$ automatically; otherwise, you can conduct that as a *post hoc* test.